# BigDecimal Incorrect Value

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal

Does anyone know why BigDecimals in the case below outputs the incorrect result?

```
double a = 2400;
double b = 3600;
double c = 8;

MathContext mc = new MathContext(14);
BigDecimal aa = new BigDecimal(2400);
BigDecimal bb = new BigDecimal(3600);
BigDecimal cc = new BigDecimal(8);

System.out.println("Doubles: " +  (a/b*c));
System.out.println("Big Ds: " +  (aa.divide(bb, mc).multiply(cc)));
```

Output:

```
Doubles: 5.333333333333333
Big Ds: 5.33333333333336
```

Thoughts and ideas are welcome.

Comment: Base-2 (double) vs. base-10 (BigDecimal) binary representation. Different kinds of rounding errors.

Comment: You cannot represent 1/3 exactly in decimal or 0.1 in binary.  You are wrong to imagine that BigDecimal or any other class changes that.

Comment: You specified 14 decimal places of precision for dividing, and you then multiplied whatever division error there was by 8.

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly as calculated manually.

```
2/3:    0.66666666666667
*8:     5.33333333333336

2/3:    0.66666666666667
                       8 x
        ----------------
                      56
                     48
                 ...     +
        ----------------
*8:     5.33333333333336
```

This is maybe counter-intuitive to many people's sense of numbers.
But the last 7 has an error of 0.1/3 too much; times 8 becomes 3 rounded up as error, so the last digit becomes 3 + error 3 == 6.

---

To minimize the rounding error on division:

```
aa.multiply(cc).divide(bb, mc)
```

The **double** calculation uses a precision of around 16 digits, just a bit more that 14.